# What effect would a Dementor have on Lord Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, dementors

Since Lord Voldemort has become less and less human, does that exclude him from the effects of a Dementor which feeds on human emotions?

I'm not asking about what would happen if a Dementor kissed Voldemort and sucked his soul out. Dementors feed off the happy emotions of people until they're left with their worst memories. Seeing that Voldemort doesn't actually feel any *happy emotions* as such, will he feel the same despair and fear if he got near a Dementor? Is there anything left in Voldemort which the Dementors could feed off?

Comment: See http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/27434/4918 Did the Dementors Affect the Death Eaters in Azkaban?  It's not really the same, but some of the arguments mentioned there can be relevant.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a canon or Word of God answer on it, but based on this answer: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15568/was-voldemort-able-to-make-a-patronus, and statements that Voldy doesn't know love, you could extrapolate that he also  can't be *happy*, which means a Dementor can't feed off his happiness.

Comment: Why do you assume he doesn't feel happiness?  I'd say it just took a different set of stimuli to make him happy.

Comment: I disagree that Voldemort cannot feel happiness. Remember, a major plot point of The Order of the Phoenix is the connection between Voldemort and Harry, that allows Harry brief glimpses into Voldemort's mind and or emotions. I recall a moment where Harry describes Voldemort being "happier than he has been in a very long time" only to find out the next day that there had been a mass breakout of death eaters from Azkaban. I cannot come up with the exact quote at the moment because I do not have access to the book currently.

Comment: For future reference: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5065/44025

Comment: Noteworthy - JK has stated that Voldemort is not immune to Boggarts - a creature that uses the targets fear against them. So there is precedent for a Dark creature using negative emotions against you working on Voldemort.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Voldemort believed that the Dementors were natural allies of the Death Eaters; I would suggest this demonstrates one of Voldemort's inherent weaknesses: The overestimation of his power (against people, creatures, etc). Voldemort *believes* the Dementors are loyal to him, but I'd be willing to bet that Voldemort in turn garnered absolutely no loyalty toward the Dementors. He believed they were under his control:

> ‘The Lestranges should stand here,’ said Voldemort quietly. ‘But they are entombed in Azkaban. They were faithful. They went to Azkaban rather than renounce me ... when Azkaban is broken open, the Lestranges will be honoured beyond their dreams. The Dementors will join us ... they are our natural allies ... we will recall the banished giants ... I shall have all my devoted servants returned to me, and an army of creatures whom all fear ...’
>
> <sub>*Goblet of Fire*</sub>

**Because Voldemort seems to believe the Dementors are his allies, it makes sense to conclude Voldemort would feel less fear, less despair, less of the frigid cold that accompanies the Dementors.**

Voldemort is a wizard so immersed in Dark Magic that he didn't even feel agony or fear when his own Horcruxes -- with the pieces of Voldemort's soul inside -- were destroyed. He wouldn't have reason to fear the Dementors. As Dementors feed on fear and despair (and souls), should Voldemore *not* fear them, he should have been able to withstand being near the Dementors far more easily than a regular wizard or witch, or Muggles.

Comment: I would say you're incorrect. Dementors feed on happy memories and leave despair. Voldemort feels happiness; it's just at the expense of others. He finds fulfillment in his ambitions and genocidal pursuits. Were the dementors true neutral, I believe they would feed on those very feelings. He bargained / tamed them to be on his side though.

Comment: @DeepDeadpool it would be interesting actually, since dementors seem to inspire remorse in people, which is Voldemort's kryptonite.

Answer (score 3):

There can be many theories over this. Since Dementors were considered among the foulest creatures, in Dumbledore's view, and Voldemort himself was also not among the best shining bunch himself, I believe there wasn't any instinctive "Hunter-Prey" feeling between both.

When the Dementors were under control of the ministry, upto first 5 books, they didn't put as harmful effects on Ministry of Magic personnel's as they did on normal wizards - this also shows they can control from whom they want to suck the hope and happiness. So it is possible that in case of Voldemort, they didn't try to harm him in any way, considering him their friend, and thus the normal ill affects of Dementor's presence wasn't much of problem for Voldemort.

Finally, Voldemort had promised them plenty of humans to feast on in return of their help and service. I doubt Dementors voluntary/involuntary would try to harm someone who is offering them so many free buffets. Also, did I mention Voldemort is the darkest and most feared wizard of the century who knew many dark arts others might not even dream of. So it is also possible he had many unknown tricks up his sleeve that might help him keeping safe from the Dementors.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: I read the question really wrong apparently, my appologies!
ORIGINAL POST:
I can't find the quote, but I remember someone asking J.K.Rowling this question, and her answer was that Voldemort would see his own death (or, his own lifeless body.)
Voldemort fears death above all else, which is partially why he makes so Horcruxes; so he cannot not truly die.